# Why do I get the error 'Forbidden.' when executing Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount using a Service Principal?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-rbac

Using Powershell in an Azure DevOps pipeline, I am trying to assign the key vault a new storage account by calling the command `Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`.

All the scripting seems to have worked so far except for that last command which fails with the `Forbidden` error.

I found [a similar issue on the MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20c254f8-1606-456f-948f-d5a9bdd999b4/addazkeyvaultmanagedstorageaccount-operation-returned-an-invalid-status-code-forbidden?forum=AzureKeyVault) but it seems the KeyVault's policies are properly set.

**Permissions of the service principal**

Here are the permissions of the service principal (named `Azure DevOps - Azure Resource Manager`) under which the command is run:

[image: Service Principal permissions]

The command is run as a Service Principal that has the `Owner` role in the subscription:

[image: Owner in Subscription]

The resource group created in that subscription is also owned by that Service Principal:

[image: Owner in Resource Group]

The [Key Vault principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell#service-principal-application-id) has been given the role of
`Storage Account Key Operator Service Role` on the storage account:

[image: KeyVault application]

The [proper policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell#give-your-user-account-permission-to-managed-storage-accounts) have configured for the Key Vault, most importantly the `Permissions to (Key Vault Managed) Storage` section:

```
Vault Name                          : accountsmanager-test
Resource Group Name                 : accountsmanager-test-global-rg
Location                            : Canada Central
Resource ID                         : /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/accountsmanager-test-global-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accountsmanager-test
Vault URI                           : https://accountsmanager-test.vault.azure.net/
Tenant ID                           : ***
SKU                                 : Standard
Enabled For Deployment?             : False
Enabled For Template Deployment?    : False
Enabled For Disk Encryption?        : False
Enabled For RBAC Authorization?     : False
Soft Delete Enabled?                : True
Soft Delete Retention Period (days) :
Access Policies                     :
                                      Tenant ID                                  : ***
                                      Object ID                                  : ***
                                      Application ID                             :
                                      Display Name                               : accountsmanager-test (6c55f481-78bf-4f5c-ab40-d8c93d7707df)
                                      Permissions to Keys                        :
                                      Permissions to Secrets                     : get
                                      Permissions to Certificates                :
                                      Permissions to (Key Vault Managed) Storage :

                                      Tenant ID                                  : ***
                                      Object ID                                  : <Service Principal's Object ID>
                                      Application ID                             :
                                      Display Name                               :
                                      Permissions to Keys                        :
                                      Permissions to Secrets                     :
                                      Permissions to Certificates                :
                                      Permissions to (Key Vault Managed) Storage : get, list, delete, set, update, regeneratekey, getsas, listsas,
                                      deletesas, setsas, recover, backup, restore, purge


Network Rule Set                    :
                                      Default Action                             : Allow
                                      Bypass                                     : AzureServices
                                      IP Rules                                   :
                                      Virtual Network Rules                      :

Tags                                :
```

**Question**

In the script, I run the following command, like described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell):

```
Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName $keyVaultName -AccountName $storageAccountName -AccountResourceId $storageAccount.Id -ActiveKeyName 'key1' -DisableAutoRegenerateKey
```

I get the following error:

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

Why do I get the error `Forbidden` when executing the command `Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little strange. I have the same issue.

But when I use the preview feature **Azure role-based access control (preview)**, I can run it successfully.

Here are my steps for your reference:

[image]

Assign key vault admin role to the service principal.

[image]

Comment: Would you happen to know what would be the corresponding powershell command to switch permission model?

Comment: I found out that I can edit my ARM template to [enable RBAC permission model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2019-09-01/vaults) when creating my KeyVault. It does the job.